# How set zoom camera to max?

Tags: android, android-camera

I use code zoom to max:

```
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
maxZoomLevel = p.getMaxZoom();
p.setZoom(maxZoomLevel);
p.set("zoom-speed", 1);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Result:

[image]

And case:  zoom to max of standard camera on my phone:

[image]

Why does my application set max zoom smaller than standard camera?
How set zoom camera to max the same standard camera?
Or Has other function increased zoom capability of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's camera app is zooming on the frame it's displaying rather than the camera itself is zooming.
Is your app, zooming to certain level?

Comment: I zoom my camera app. But i had zoom to max zoom level. but still smaller than max of standard camera.

Comment: Can you post one more image without setting any zoom level in your app?

Comment: ok. You can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71ivw9px5qfzrps/4270000020_4270100010201406100001_20140610202943_thumb.png

Comment: It means you are able to zoom, but not to the extent of your camera app as your camera app is doing a digital zoom inb addition to optical zoom.. You can search how to do digital zoom if you want.

Comment: I search how to do digital zoom, but not exist doc. Have you got?